# Problem while registering a model in admin.py file (Django)

Tags: python, django

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

class TodoListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title",  "created", "due_date")

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)

admin.site.register(models.TodoList, TodoListAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

I am trying to register two models in my Django admin.py file inside the app directory
The model file is as follows :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ToDoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    contents = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    due_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

For some reason , there is no problem with Category class but I am encountering an error with ToDoList class . Django is showing the following error

```
  admin.site.register(models.TodoList, TodoListAdmin)
AttributeError: module 'todolist.models' has no attribute 'TodoList'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all in the spelling bro,

Your class instance is

> ToDoList

and in your

> admin.site.register()

You are making reference to

> Todolist

Change the "d" in your admin.site.register() to uppercase

That is

> admin.site.register(models.ToDoList, TodoListAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

You just typo, change `TodoList` with `ToDoList`.